# Using a column reference for a vlookup formula

Tags: excel

When inserting a table in Excel you can refer to:

- the data range `Table[#data]`
- header range `Table[#header]`
- full column range `Table[column name]` or
- value of current row under certain column `Table[@[colum name]]`

which makes formulas very easy to read: `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)` becomes

`=COUNTIF(Suppliers[IBAN],Suppliers[@[IBAN]])`

to quickly check for duplicates (IBAN) of the current row value.

I'm now trying to convert `=VLOOKUP([@SupplierCode],Suppliers[Code],2,False)` into

`=VLOOKUP([@SupplierCode],Suppliers[Code],Suppliers[Name],False)`

So in other words, **a way to get the column index of a column within a tableObject to use it in a formula (i.e. vlookup)**.

I could probably write a VBA function that does this, but I'm trying to find out if Excel has a way to handle this **without VBA code**

**The VBA solution I do not want** (but might settle for in case it is not possible):

```vb
Public Function GetColumnIndex(TableName As String, ColumName As String) As Long
    GetColumnIndex = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(TableName).ListColumns(ColumName).Index
End Function
```

allowing me to write: `=VLOOKUP([@SupplierCode],Suppliers,GetColumnIndex("suppliers","Name"),FALSE)`

works, as long as the tables are on the same sheet

Comment: If I've understood correctly, you could use Match(): eg =VLOOKUP(@SupplierCode,Suppliers[Code],MATCH("??Name??",Suppliers[#Headers],0),False)

Comment: no Suppliers[??Name??] is not valid, I use it as a placeholder of how I expect this to work.

Comment: So what happens if you replace "??Name??" with whatever column name you want to look up or a cell reference with the name you want?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see you put Match in there already, if you post it as the answer I'll accept it. I somehow came to the same conclusion after thinking about it more, without realizing you had already provided the answer

Comment: Ok, now added as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now added as answer:
`=MATCH("Name",Suppliers[#Headers],0)` gives the index of the header matching the name so

The only way I can think to do it without VBA is to use the Match() function

`=VLOOKUP([@SupplierCode],Suppliers,MATCH("Name",Suppliers[#Headers],0),FALSE)`

Comment: sorry to jump on this as it's a separate question, do you know if you can use Table[Column] for a data validation list?

Comment: I don't think you can directly, but if you create a named range (use ctrl + f3 to open the Name Manager) with your Table[Column] reference in Refers To, you can set this named range as the Data Validation list.

Comment: I would also spend some time looking at this page http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm. I find named ranges much more versatile than the built in tables.

Comment: @Dave Dynamic ranges do have a down-side in a bigger processing overhead because, like conditional formats, **they are recalculated every time recalculation is called.**

Comment: Thanks Mark, I do forget this point as I mainly work with data sets that aren't affected badly by recalculation times

Comment: @VincentDeSmet Yes, that would be a separate question to Google. There are many answers out there.

Answer (score 2):

Working with tables, I think a better option is to replace the VLOOKUP formula with the INDEX formula in this way:

`=INDEX(MyTableName[NameOfFieldContainingReturnValue],MATCH(LookupValue,MyTableName[NameOfFieldContainingLookupValue],0))`

Some comments:

- Index function can reference to a simple column in this way: `=INDEX(MyTableName[FieldName];4)`
- This would return the value in 4th row in the column 'FieldName'
- As we don't know the row number, we can use MATCH in the column containing the lookup value (this would be the most left column in the case of using vlookup formula).

Answer (score 1):

I've found this link invaluable [Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-a547e45e-3589-4417-b611-abb7e5d3f912/)

I created a little Suppliers table with 2 columns, SupplierCode and Name then added a couple of entries below each heading.

When I pasted your `=VLOOKUP(@SupplierCode,Suppliers[Code],2,False)`

Into a a cell to the right of the 1st row of my table I was confronted with a message I've never seen before:

[image: Excel alert]

and when closed the `@Supplier` part of your formula was highlighted. Changing that to `Suppliers[@SupplierCode]` fixed that problem.

Assuming SupplierCode is in the first column of your table you can find the lookup column using the MATCH function within your VLOOKUP function as you have already discovered.

Comment: thank you for clarifying I should have put the supplier code between brackets - I actually was testing with a cell ref and put the @suppliercode as an example.

Comment: I edited my question to avoid other people trying out the examples I put running into the same error

Comment: The question should be left as it was to keep the answers and comments in context.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be generalized to cases where the lookup value is not in the first column:

```
=VLOOKUP("g";Table[[LookupColumn]:[ValueColumn]];MATCH("ValueColumn";Table[[#Headers];[LookupColumn]:[ValueColumn]];0);FALSE)
```

like in the following example:

[image]